# Typeorm campo default, no inserta en la Bd

Tags: typeorm, nestjs

Tengo un esquema de bd(tabla Drivers) que esta tomando X cantidad de campos de los cuales hablaré solo 3.
Esto es activo, fecha creación y fecha modificación.
En la Bd (que es postgres) están como obligatorios.
Mi tema radica en que estoy utilizando typeorm en nestjs, creé mi entidad y le puse que estos campos fueran DEFAULT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que si quiero agregar un registro en esta tabla solo pongo los otros datos y estos 3 al no ponerlos yo, los debería proporcionar la BD, esto me funcionó ayer, cuando lo hice en mi bd local. Pero ahora al usar la bd que me entregó mi jefa me falla diciendo que necesita esos 3 campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En que puedo estar fallando? Que otra info pueden necesitar de mi para tener mas claridad?
Espero que me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias

---o----

**Actualización**

Me puse a comparar ambas bd y la local los campos en bd se crearon así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La que me pasó mi jefa esa parte esta vacía
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento hacer un insert, esta es la query que me entrega nestJs

```
query: INSERT INTO "gdd"."driver"("rut", "name", "phone", "active", "create_date", "mod_date", "transport_company_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $4) RETURNING "driver_id", "active", "create_date", "mod_date" -- PARAMETERS: ["11111111-8","Juan Perez2","56991554408",1]
query failed: INSERT INTO "gdd"."driver"("rut", "name", "phone", "active", "create_date", "mod_date", "transport_company_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $4) RETURNING "driver_id", "active", "create_date", "mod_date" -- PARAMETERS: ["11111111-8","Juan Perez2","56991554408",1]
error: error: null value in column "create_date" of relation "driver" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Y si pruebas colocando los campos como obligatorios? Cambiando el símbolo de pregunta (`active?`) por exclamación (`active!`), además si no quieres que no sean nulos, agrega a los atributos un `nulleable: false`

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. El tema es que si pongo active! mis dtos comienzan a fallar porque solo se le esta indicando el campo que necesita recibir (que son otros 4), entonces el tema no va por ahi. Ahora, si pongo `nulleable:false` no generó ningun cambio :(

Comment: muestranos tu query por favor

Comment: @BetaM Listo amigo, actualice el post, gracias por tu tiempo